# Using a container object as a mask

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a 2D Game.

I'm trying to move an object which is within another object an make it disappear once it's out of the container object boundaries (just like in web development a **div** with attribute **overflow** set to **hidden**).

**NOTE**: I can move the object, that's not the issue. But I cannot make the parent object behave as a container.

See snippet for clarification.

```css
.blue {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.red {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.yellow {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  left: 75px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
  <div class="red">
    <div class="yellow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The blue square represents the scene. The red rectangle is the container object. The yellow square is a nested object. What I'm trying to achieve is this: move up the yellow square until it gets out of sight by not being inside the visible area of the red rectangle anymore.

Unfortunately, despite being nested in the red rectangle object, the yellow square object is still visible in the scene (blue square) whenever I move it up.

I'm a total JR in unity and I know this question is monumentally silly, but I haven't found (or at least that's what I think) an answer regarding how to tackle this.

Comment: *"What I'm trying to achieve is this: move up the yellow square until it gets out of sight by not being inside the visible area of the red rectangle anymore."* You need to break this into two tasks an ask a new question for each one. 1.How to move 2D object? 2.How detect when two objects are not overlapping? With these two questions, you'll have a solution. You on't even have to ask them. Googling them should yield answer

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm going to update my question so it's clear where I'm stuck at: I can move the object, that's not the issue. But I cannot make the parent object a proper container.

Comment: BTW, I wrote "Unfortunately, despite being nested in the red rectangle object, the yellow square object is still visible in the scene (blue square) **whenever I move it up**". So it's obvious I'm moving the yellow square already, something you would be aware of, had you read the whole question carefully. With all due respect.

Comment: I've been googling the whole day looking for an answer with no success. This is my last resource. I'm about to throw the towel to be honest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Sprite Masks` are what you're looking for.

Here is the manual of how to use them: 

### Sprite Masks

Answer (score 1):

If it is 2D use sprite mask. If in 3D I Think you can achieve this if you use multiple cameras. Create another camera which renders only red and yellow square. And adjust camera size to Red sqaure.

Answer (score 0):

Hello did you try Collider2D? Colliders have function isTouching so you can actually 
 check whether the yellow box is inside the red one or not. if they don't touch, you can make it disappear by disabling renderer

```
gameobject.getCompponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
```

here is the reference to the method:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouching.html

Comment: Thanks @Michal,  I'm gonna try that. Notice that the thing is: to make the yellow square disappear gradually while "trespassing" the parent object boundaries. So the yellow square will be half visible if half of it is inside the parent object and half of it is not.

Comment: Sorry then, I misunderstood and it will be better to use sprite mask as suggested by others